# Any suggestions on getting xxhdpi working in the android emulator?

Tags: android

I've tried manually configuring an AVD to support xxhdpi (480 dpi), however the android emulator maxes out at xhdpi (320 dpi).

Yes, the docs say that xhdpi will scale, however, I'd like to see it working.

I'm currently attempting to build android from the source code, to see if I can tweak anything manually.

Comment: Have you found anything since asking this?  I'd like to be able to do it as well.

Answer (score 13):

This can be accomplished with a few additional adb-commands after the emulator has started. Taken from an installation troubleshooting page at developer.sonymobile.com (http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/), the following statement is available:

> In the Android SDK Tools version 21.1, the xxhdpi screen resolution for the emulator display is not yet supported. However, you could do a manual override of the LCD properties of the emulator. This will ensure that the correct resources are being dispatched for the Xperia™ Z emulator. To do so, please execute the following in your
>   command line after the Xperia™ Z emulator has completed the boot sequence:
>
> > adb shell setprop qemu.sf.lcd_density 480
> >
> > adb shell stop
> >
> > adb shell start
>
> The emulator will then restart. After it has rebooted the emulator should use the correct screen density and UI scaling. We recommend you to execute these commends using a batch file or a shell script if you are using these settings often.

Comment: I've tried this multiple times and every time the emulator restarts it just crashes.  Has anyone been able to have this not happen? I'm running my emulator on windows 8 machine.

Comment: +1 for sharing this post, i have gone through it, Sony done an excellent Job. [Post about XXHDPI may help you](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-develop-android-application-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to set AVD settings to Use Host GPU. Unfortunately with this Snapshot will be disabled. Confirmed with SDK Tools 22.3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Using this make avd for xxhdpi emulator]
for making xxhdpi avd use this.