# Why there is no "Nexus 5" in AVD Manager? What option to use instead?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have installed the latest Android SDK (22.3). But there is no "Nexus 5" option in AVD Manager. Please see the picture:

[image]

What option should I instead to emulate Nexus 5?

I'm Android development newbie.

Comment: Perhaps they haven't created it yet.

Comment: @krsteeve, Nexus 5 is created already http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php

Comment: I meant the Nexus 5 **emulator**.

Answer (score 17):

The [Nexus 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_5) got a 4.95-inch screen at 1080×1920 (1080p) screen resolution, 2 GB RAM, front-and-back cameras. This is the correct settings when creating a custom device definition.

Both the Nexus 4 and the Nexus 5 have 2 GB RAM, but Google's device definition for the Nexus 4 has the RAM set to 1907 MB, hence I've used that here for the Nexus 5 too.

[image]

Comment: When I use these settings the emulator creates an AVD that uses layout-large resources even though I specify normal and the actual Nexus 5 is not a 'large' size device

Comment: @KevinMark, Both the Nexus 4 and the Nexus 5 have 2 GB RAM, but Google's device definition for the Nexus 4 has the RAM set to 1907 MB, hence I've used that here for the Nexus 5 too.

Comment: @Fred, I wasn't disagreeing with you. 1907 MiB (mebibytes) is equal to 2 GB (gigabytes).

Comment: has anyone tried using the actual device?  @dangVarmit have you resolved that issue?  Seems to be more important than getting the emulator to work..it uses sw480dp btw

Comment: yes I have a Nexus 5.  It's a bit hacky but you can correct the emulator's display after it loads by following the steps in this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919341/any-suggestions-on-getting-xxhdpi-working-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: What should the internal storage number be set to when you add a device using the profile? Any "proper" setting for the Emulation Options or do they all work fine?

Comment: @jep, it really doesn't matter. The Nexus comes with 16 or 32 GB internal storage. But you can use anything you want.

Comment: forgive me but isnt 2048mb equal to 2gb or is it somehow dfferent for ram?

Comment: @martinseal1987, yes 2 GB equals 2048 MB. However the Nexus 4 has 2 GB and Google set the RAM to 1907 MB, so I used the same on the Nexus 5 template.

Answer (score 2):

I can create a device myself. Just choose a `Device Definition` tab. There is a button `New Device...`. Click it, provide characteristics for a device and click a `Create Device` button.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the specific properties we'd have to fill in to create the device?