# Android XXHDPI Density

Tags: android, screen-density

I'm facing the next problem:

I'm testing my app in a samsung S4 emulator (XXHDPI). When i ask for the density with getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density it returns 2.625 and not 3. Thats a problem because all the Views in my activities are smaller because it multiply all my views x 2,625 and not 3.

So I have two oquestions:

1) Why is this happening?
2) How to fix this, and return 3.

Thanks

Comment: You can't change the device resolution. Android devices are about diversity, which includes screen sizes and resolutions. You need to deal with non pixel perfect dimensions, and see how apps you already have on your phone deal with it properly

Comment: "samsung S4 emulator (XXHDPI)" -- if you mean a Galaxy S4, with a screen resolution of 1920x1080, and a diagonal screen size of 5.0 inches, the actual density is 441 dpi. That would be closest to [`DENSITY_420`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_420), though that did not exist when the Galaxy S4 was released. So, what version of Android are you running on this emulator, and what makes you think that is it set for `xxhdpi`?

Comment: @CommonsWare My emulator of Samsung Galaxy S4: 1080 x 1920 and diagonal screen size of 4,99 inches. Has a density of 420 dpi. Im running API 23. 
I think is xxhdpi because I read it.

Comment: "Has a density of 420 dpi" -- this matches your 2.625 value. IOW, for an API Level 23 emulator, it is behaving much as an API Level 23 device would behave, if it had the same specifications.

Comment: So, how can i create an emulator with density of xxhdpi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any suggestions on getting xxhdpi working in the android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919341/any-suggestions-on-getting-xxhdpi-working-in-the-android-emulator)

Comment: Ya salio el toca pito @petey